# How can I add a line break after each table?

Tags: php

Below is my LOC, I'm confused how can i add a br tag to give space after each table? I'm new on programming.

```
<?php

for ($num=1; $num <=10 ; $num++) { 

    for ($i=1; $i<=12 ; $i++) 
    { 

        echo "$num*$i"."=". $num*$i;
        echo "<br>";

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: add `<hr>`or `<br>` between `}}`

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add another `<br>` in your first loop like so:

```
<?php
  for ($num=1; $num <=10 ; $num++) { 
    for ($i=1; $i<=12 ; $i++) 
    { 

    echo "$num*$i"."=". $num*$i;
    echo "<br>";

    }
  echo "<br>";
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all this not a table and if you want to give '
' between two loop then
Try like this

```
<?php
for ($num=1; $num <=10 ; $num++) { 

for ($i=1; $i<=12 ; $i++) 
{ 

    echo "$num*$i"."=". $num*$i;
    echo "<br>";

}
 echo "<br>";
}
?>
```